# EJ2 Grid, Pulling The Id from the Row

Tags: javascript, grid, ej2-syncfusion

I am working the an EJ2 Grid and I have an Edit and Delete option.  With the EJ grid passing the Id field worked with no issues with the onClick. The same thing is not working with the EJ2 Grid.

```
        var grid = new ej.grids.Grid({
        dataSource: @Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject((Model), new JavaScriptDateTimeConverter())),
        allowExcelExport: true,
        allowPdfExport: true,
        toolbar: ['ExcelExport', 'PdfExport', 'CsvExport'],
        allowSelection: true,
        allowFiltering: true,
        allowSorting: true,
        //allowPaging: true,
        allowNumberFormatting: true,
        enableVirtualization: true,
        filterSettings: { type: 'Excel' },
        selectionSettings: { persistSelection: true, type: "Multiple", checkboxOnly: true },
        enableHover: false,
        enableHeaderFocus: true,
        height: 600,
        rowHeight: 38,
        columns: [
            { field: "Id", visible: false, allowEditing: false },
            { field: "Name",                  headerText: "Name",               width: 100 },
            { field: "ElectionDate",          headerText: "ElectionDate",       width: 80, format: "MM/dd/yyyy"},
            { field: "RegistrationClose",     headerText: "Registration Close", width: 80, format: "MM/dd/yyyy", },
            { field: "RegularAbsenteeStart",  headerText: "Absentee Start",     width: 80, format: "MM/dd/yyyy"},
            { field: "EarlyVotingStart",      headerText: "Early Voting Start", width: 80, format: "MM/dd/yyyy"},
            { field: "GraceVotingStart",      headerText: "Grace Voting Start", width: 80, format: "MM/dd/yyyy",},
            { field: "ElectionTypeName",      headerText: "ElectionType",       width: 110, },
            { field: "Active",                headerText: "Active",             width: 70 },
            {
                headerText: "",
                template: '<a href="#" onclick="Edit({{:Id}})">Edit</a>',
                width: 40,
                textAlign: "center"
            },
            {
                headerText: "",
                template: '<a href="#" data-url="@Url.Action("Delete")/{{:Id}}" data-name="{{:Name}}" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirmModal">Delete</a>',
                width: 40,
                textAlign: "center"
            },
        ],
        //pageSettings: { pageSizes: true, pageSize: 8 }
    });

    grid.appendTo("#dataGrid_EJ2");
```

Answer (score 0):

The template changed in EJ2.  EJ it was {{:Id}} EJ2 it changed to ${Id}

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).